# Why is my DR AG database in the "recovery pending" state?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, availability-groups, failover

I am trying to build an architecture where we get automatic failover for both HA and DR for our DBs using SQL Server 2016 AlwaysOn Availability Groups.  When I tested this using only one Availability Group, the DR DB said it was in a 'recovery pending state'.

Do I need to put the same DB on two Availability Groups to avoid the Quorum problem (one for HA and one for DR)?

Is it possible to have one DB on 2 AGs (one AG for a AG Cluster and one only for DR)?

Comment: What version of Windows Server?  How do you have cluster quorum configured?  Note that an AG will _never_ automatically fail over to an asynchronous replica, as that might involve data loss.  And for DR you normally use an asynchronous replica in a remote data center.

Comment: You would normally have a fileshare ressource in your cluster to avoid Quorum problem.
How many node will you have ? It's frequent to have 3 nodes for that kind of setup.
2 node in the same site in "synchronous" mode (this will have automatic failover and will provide HA)
1 node in another site in "Asynchronous" mode (this one will not have automatic failover and will be there for DR (with some possible data loss).

Comment: We tried with 2 nodes and that could be our issue.  Windows server 2012 with SQL Server 2016.  Let me check if we did this asyn or syn?  Thanks

Comment: Is this happening when the fail-over happens during a large transaction?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put one database into multiple availability groups. The likely cause of the recovery pending state is related to your cluster configuration. If you only have two nodes and no file share or disk witness then your cluster can sustain 0 node failures.

If you're testing by shutting down node 1 and you don't have a quorum witness (file share or disk) then node 2's cluster service will stop and the AG will not bring the databases online.

Run a cluster validation to confirm how many node failures the cluster can sustain (needs to be at least 1) and validate your quorum configuration.

Comment: My current employer, we have file shares but only two node clusters. MS says they think it's caused by a process being blocked by anti-virus or another installed program on the server but they can't confirm until we recreate a fail-over and run a process monitoring utility.